Unity - Ray casting only works from origin
I am trying to shoot a ray from the position of my gun in the direction my mouse is at when i click shoot.
This works when my character is in the centre of the screen but then offsets in whatever distance I move away from the origin.
Itill has the same origin point of the ray (my gun) but the direction of the ray will not be where my mouse is (will be ofsett by my distance from 0,0,0).
Have tried numerous fixes, would appreciate any help.




using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public int gunDamage = 5;

    [SerializeField] Vector3 worldPosition;
    Vector3 mousePos;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
       
        worldPosition.z = 0;


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))

            {
            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            //mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
            worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
            worldPosition.z = 0;
            RaycastHit2D hits = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, worldPosition);
             Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, worldPosition);
           
            if(hits.collider != null)
            {
                Health es = hits.collider.GetComponent<Health>();
                es.TakeDamage(gunDamage);
            }

        }

       
    }
}





Have tried using Vector 3 and 2. also tried using a ray to calc the position of the mouse instead of using screentoworldpoint. same issue.

because for some reason you believe that a position is a direction?

The second parameter of Physics2D.Raycast is direction
You need to specify a direction to raycast in, not the target global position you're raycasting towards. You were raycasting the direction from 0,0 to the mouse, that's why if the player wasn't at 0,0 anymore your raycast wouldn't work.
Use this code instead to calculate the correct direction first.
Vector3 direction = (worldPosition - transform.position).normalized;
RaycastHit2D hits = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction);

